# How to fetch and show data (on new activity) from SQLite in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am confused what mistake i am making to fetch passWord against username (I am new here and to android :) so sorry if i make any mistake in asking question)
        Here's LoginDatabaseAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+ "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text,MOBILENO int); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password,String mobileNumber)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
        newValues.put("MOBILENO", mobileNumber);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
    {
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }   
    public String getSingleEntry(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST...!!!";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        // String mobileNumber=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MOBILENO"));
        cursor.close();
        return "Password="+password;

    }
    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password,String mobileNumber)
    {
        // Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
        updatedValues.put("MOBILENO", mobileNumber);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
    }           
}
```

and SignupActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUpActivity extends Activity
{
EditText     editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword,editTextMobileNo;
Button btnCreateAccount;

Button btnfetch;
TextView sv;

LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get Refferences of Views
    editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
    editTextMobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileNo);

    btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
        String mobileNumber=editTextMobileNo.getText().toString();

        // check if any of the fields are vaccant
        if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||mobileNumber.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Your Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        // check if both password matches
        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confirm Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Save the Data in Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password,mobileNumber);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

    btnfetch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnshow);
    btnfetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshow);
            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String pass=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(userName);
            sv.setText(pass);
        }
    }); 

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the following below on any update, delete, or insert query.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // CALL insert, update or delete 
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

example below:

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
newValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
newValues.put("MOBILENO", mobileNumber);

db.beginTransaction();
try {      
    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention using a Content Provider is way better, and could with CursorAdapters and LoaderCallBacks :)

Comment: Using `catch` is a bad idea when you don't actually handle the exception. And how does this answer the question?

Comment: the catching of errors is not for me to decide for  what he wants to catch, just simply helping resolve future insert, update and deletes, the Content Provider , or using an ORM like ActiveAndroid :)  IS a better route to go than just using SQLiteDatabase. The answer is what you do with the advice, future and current problems will be resolved

Comment: mates i know its not the greatest question ever asked :P  as i mentioned i am new here and learning things that's why i asked here, and if anybody could answer this question, that would be extremely helpful thanks.

Comment: Would you mind learning SimpleContentProvider instead or is the above a requirement ? github link provided https://github.com/mitmel/SimpleContentProvider

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have a `DATABASE_CREATE` command in your `LoginDataBaseAdapter` class, but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Are you sure you actually create the LOGIN table in your database? Your `DataBaseHelper` class (whose contents you didn't provide) should contain something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

The `onCreate` method is invoked when your database is first created, so make sure you delete the old database first. (Uninstalling your application takes care of that.)

If that doesn't work, please provide more information on what error you're getting, including the exception stack trace (if any) copied from logcat.